# ServiceBusTrigger picks up the wrong configuration file

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have 4 config files in my azure function project representing 4 environments.

[image: My configs]

I have the following code to red the env specific file based on `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`

```
        var executionContextOptions = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider()
        .GetService<IOptions<ExecutionContextOptions>>().Value;

        var currentDirectory = executionContextOptions.AppDirectory;

        var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(currentDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile($"local.settings.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
         builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);
```

I am able to access the keys via DI like `_configuration.GetSection("Values")`
I now have a ServiceBusTrigger

```
[FunctionName("FuncEmployeeMessageActivity")]
    public static void FuncEmployeeMessageActivity(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("queue-xxxxx", Connection = "ServiceBus")] string message,
    ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            // Process the message received from the Service Bus queue.
            log.LogInformation($"Received message: {message}");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Here the `Connection` property is looking for the key `ServiceBus` inside `local.settings.json` instead of `local.dev.settings.json` as I have `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` set to `dev` in my VS. How can I resolve this ?

> Warning: Cannot find value named 'ServiceBus' in local.settings.json
> that matches 'connection' property set on 'serviceBusTrigger'

Answer (score 1):

At this time you can’t. Triggers, such as Azure Service Bus, with a connection string require connection string to be found in `local.settings.json` during development, and set as an environment variable via settings when deployed.

[This thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1884) is for the new SDK but is still relevant to your question, with details.